# Is a conditional image creation with add_image_size possible and which would be the best hook?

Tags: images, responsive

I try to get the Picturefill solution described [here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/diy-truly-responsive-images-on-your-wordpress-website/) running with the latest Wordpress install. One thing I wonder is the following. Would it be basically possible to only conditionally create image versions. Normally you have something like that in your functions.php:

```
add_image_size('res-small', 410, 9999);
add_image_size('res-medium',750, 9999);
add_image_size('res-large', 920, 9999);
```

But if you have different scenarios and constraints in one layout it might require more than 3 or 6 image versions (if you include the standard WP ones too)- e.g. 9 or even more. So would it be possible to conditionally create sets of images e.g. :

```
<?php
if($hook == x) {
    add_image_size('bps1-small', 410, 9999);
    add_image_size('bps1-medium',750, 9999);
    add_image_size('bps1-large', 920, 9999);
}
else if ($hook ==y) {
    add_image_size('bps2-small', 360, 9999);
    add_image_size('bps2-middle', 520, 9999);
    add_image_size('bps2-middle', 820, 9999);
}
else {
    add_image_size('bp3-small', 220, 9999);
    add_image_size('bp3-middle', 820, 9999);
    add_image_size('bp3-large', 1200, 9999);
}
?>
```

Would that basically work or does WP require to generate EVERY image size listed in the functions.php or is there an even more elegant way? Unfortunately I was unable to test it yet cuz i am out of ideas which would be a practical hook  after which the if function could distinguish which set of images it should create. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks a lot Ralf

Comment: The typical approach is to adjust for image sizes to be generated first time they are requested rather than when image initially uploaded.